# firebase angularfire2 typeahead query not working

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to cunstruct a typeahead query. What i have right now is returning an empty string. I'm a brand new to using firebase so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
list(searchString, path) {
    const list: AngularFireList<IdNamePair> = this.fireBase.list(path, ref => ref
        .orderByChild('name')
        .startAt(searchString)
        .endAt('\uf8ff')
    );
    return list;
}

getUsersTypeAhead(searchString: string) {
    return this.list(searchString, '/users').snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(items => items.map(item => ({
            id: item.key,
            ...item.payload.val()
        })))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should do as follows:

```
list(searchString, path) {
    const list: AngularFireList<IdNamePair> = this.fireBase.list(path, ref => ref
        .orderByChild('name')
        .startAt(searchString)
        .endAt(searchString + '\uf8ff')
    );
    return list;
}
```

I haven't tested it with angularfire but with the Javascript SDK the following query works correctly:

```
ref
.orderByChild('name')
.startAt(searchString)
.endAt(searchString + '\uf8ff')
```

Comment: yea i forgot `searchString + '\uf8ff'`. do you this seems to work, but only on case match. i there a work around for this?

Comment: What you could do is to save, "under the hood", an extra field with the value in upper case and query on this field. It is quite common in the NoSQL world to duplicate data.